# How do I get the value for 'Option Compare' at runtime?

Tags: .net, vb.net

For debugging purposes, is it possible to get the value of `Option Compare` at runtime?

(I am working on a legacy [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application that uses [InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with the first parameter as `String` (three-parameter-version of Instr), without the third parameter that is then determined by [Option Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t3khw5f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). `Option Compare Text` supposedly makes InStr case-insensitive; the default is `Option Compare Binary`.)

Comment: Perform a set of comparisons whose results distinguish which compare option is set? I'm still not sure I see why this has to be determined at runtime (nor how this info will be used)

Comment: I would like to positively know what the value is, without relying on inspection of code or project settings or writing extra code which may not be possible (for instance, when debugging a .NET assembly (DLL file that the main application is using) where only the PDB file is available for use in debugging).

Comment: Use String.IndexOf instead of InStr, it's not dependent on Option Compare

Answer (score 6):

The option setting is only known at compile time.  The compiler handles this with the OptionCompareAttribute attribute.  When present on an optional parameter, it substitutes the option setting.  Which inspires this function:

```
Function GetOptionCompare(<CompilerServices.OptionCompare()> _
                          Optional ByVal Compare As CompareMethod = CompareMethod.Binary) As CompareMethod
    Return Compare
End Function
```

This however doesn't work for unguessable reasons.  Punt the problem, simply take advantage of the difference between the compare methods:

```
Function GetOptionCompare() As CompareMethod
    Return IIf("A" = "a", CompareMethod.Text, CompareMethod.Binary)
End Function
```

Do beware that Option Compare can be a per-source file setting, this function can only work when you rely on the Visual Studio default.  That's a bit iffy.  Well, pretty iffy.  Well, it's bad.  Avoid having to want to know the setting.